# How to arrange all ipaddresses in ascending order in ipaddress array in c#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

How to arrange all ipaddresses in ascending order in ipaddress array in c#
I have array of ipaddress class

```
ipaddress[] device = new ipaddress[10];
```

it has different ip value and i want to arrange them in ascending order

Comment: Show your sample IP's and the desired order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the *Version-trick*:

sample-data:

```
IPAddress[] ips = new[]{
        IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.4"),
        IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.5"),
        IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.1"),
        IPAddress.Parse("10.152.16.23"),
        IPAddress.Parse("69.52.220.44"),
    };
```

order ascending:

```
var sortedIps = ips
    .Select(ip => Version.Parse(ip.ToString()))
    .OrderBy(v => v)
    .Select(v => IPAddress.Parse(v.ToString()))
    .ToArray();
```

result:

```
{10.152.16.23}  System.Net.IPAddress
{69.52.220.44}  System.Net.IPAddress
{192.168.1.4}   System.Net.IPAddress
{192.168.1.5}   System.Net.IPAddress
{192.168.2.1}   System.Net.IPAddress
```

**Update**

> You: It give this error 'System.Version' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Parse'.
>   Me:  Then you're not using at least .NET framework 4.0.
>   [Version.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.parse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
>   You: Yes I am using .NET framwork 3.5 So What change I will need to
>   do?

Then you could use  [`IPAddress.GetAddressBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for `Enumerable.OrderBy`/ `ThenBy`:

```
sortedIps = ips
    .Select(ip => new { IP = ip, Bytes = ip.GetAddressBytes() })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Bytes[0]).ThenBy(x => x.Bytes[1]).ThenBy(x => x.Bytes[2]).ThenBy(x => x.Bytes[3])
    .Select(x => x.IP)
    .ToArray();
```

**Update2**

> Thanks, but it t stops if any member of array is null.if we want to
>   work with that array which contains some null value. I want to order null values last.

Then use this query which uses a `Byte[]` with `Byte.MaxValue` for null values:

```
var sortedIps = ips
    .Select(ip => new { 
        IP = ip,
        Bytes = ip == null
            ? new[] { Byte.MaxValue, Byte.MaxValue, Byte.MaxValue, Byte.MaxValue }
            : ip.GetAddressBytes() 
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Bytes[0]).ThenBy(x => x.Bytes[1]).ThenBy(x => x.Bytes[2]).ThenBy(x => x.Bytes[3])
    .Select(x => x.IP)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick responce but it give this error
'System.Version' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'.

Comment: @Kevan: Then you're not using at least .NET framework 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.parse(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes I am using .NET framwork 3.5
So What change I will need to do?

Comment: @Kevan: Updated my answer to show a different approach using `IPAddress.GetAddressBytes`.

Comment: Thanks Man this answer worked!but it works only when all members of array are initiallised with some value.it stops if any member of array is null.if we want to work with that array which contains some null value also then what to do.?

Comment: @Kevan: Define _work with_, how do you want to order a null-IP, first or last?

Comment: I want to order null ip at last.

Comment: Great man you made my work so easy!it works completely as I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if i'm correct:

```
var list = new string[5];
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why `= new string[]` ? `ToArray()` creates a new array already, so you're just wasting time allocating memory on the heap, that you'll never use.

Comment: And the OrderBy is only available on a list and it needs to be converted back to an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq for that

```
using System.Linq;

ipaddress[] sortedDevice1 = device.OrderBy(d => d.IP).ToArray(); // assuming the ip address is saved in a field named 'IP'
ipaddress[] sortedDevice2 = device.OrderByDescending(d => d.IP).ToArray(); // if you need it sorted by descending order
```

If your `IP` field is not a `string`, you may want to implement the `IComparable` interface for the `IP` field, to improve the sorting quality, i.e: getting `11.100 > 2.100` instead of `2.100 > 11.100`

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the Array.Sort methods, [Array.Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx) among others. Example is simple:

```
Array.Sort(device, (a,b) => [compare here, return int] );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 Array.Sort(devices, (d1, d2) => d1.IPValue.CompareTo(d2.IPValue));
```

But better use `List` instead of `Array`